# SHA-256 and KECCAK-256 swap

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha, keccak

From one input I got two different results (via SHA3 (1) and via KECCAK256 (2)).

Is it possible to find a possible input for the Keccak-256 function that would result in the same output hash, given the known input and output for the SHA3-256?

It seems that correct answer is no, but maybe input and output information from SHA3 can accelerate the bruteforce or other techniques?

Comment: Sound more like topic for https://crypto.stackexchange.com.